# Javascript Interview Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a javascript function that would call on button click but through a div class id. How to write that?

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
     <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

after click it should write message `I am here`.

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to write your code for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/8e06dqz1/

Comment: See this.. http://jsfiddle.net/qg2scem2/

Comment: they have not write button id and i am not allowed to write any thing in html

Comment: @AleyaAli check my answer. have not assign any id or class to button

Comment: please write your effort, what you have done for fulfilling your task.

Comment: @AleyaAli There is a thing called GOOGLE you should try that sometime...

Comment: @AleyaAli any reason to deselect as answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple. just you will have to call click function with div class.
like this

```
$('.content').click(function(){
  alert("You have done");
})
```

[Here is DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/faoua1qk/)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript solution for the html provided:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].onclick = function () {alert("I am here");};
```

Javascript for any button in the div:

```
message = function () {
  alert("I am here");
};
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].children;
for (var i in items) {
  if (items[i].tagName == "BUTTON") {
    items[i].onclick = message;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){

      $(".content").find("button").on("click",function(){
        alert("I am here");
      });
});
```

Comment: I was not allowed to write any thing in code, and button id was not given there just div id was provided

Comment: no button id was given and I am not allowed to modify any thing in html tag